# Flatten a nested object in MongoDB and rename

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have documents like this

```
{
    "id" : "1415166669",
    "color" : {
        "14" : "Silver"
    },
    "name":"Random Name"
}
```

where the key inside color can change, i.e Next Document may look like this

```
{
    "id" : "1415126969",
    "color" : {
        "11" : "Gold"
    },
    "name":"Random Name 2"
}
```

I want to flatten and rename them so that my documents have a similar structure as follows:

```
{
    "id" : "1415126969",
    "color"  : "Gold"
    "name":"Random Name 2"
}
```

and

```
{
    "id" : "1415166669",
    "color" : "Silver"
    "name":"Random Name"
}
```

I tried using the aggregation pipeline but I am not sure how to proceed further. 
Also can anyone suggest a way using Robomongo, that would be nice as well.

Comment: If you are intending change the values in your collection, then a simple loop in code is the best approach. It is possible in the aggregation framework with MongoDB 3.4, but it's also a lot more complex than the code to run in a loop. Also all the aggregation framework can do is write to a "new" collection with `$out`. So you should not use that method unless the collection is really large.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would run a simple JavaScript loop for this, since it's going to be quite quick and easy to code. It can also be applied to the same collection:

```
var ops = [];

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  let color;
  Object.keys(doc.color).forEach(function(key) {
    color = doc.color[key];
  });
  ops = [
    ...ops,
    { "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": { "$set": { "color": color } }
    }}
  ];
  if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
     ops = [];
  }
})

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
   ops = [];
}
```

So you basically traverse the "keys" of the object and get the value, which later we write back to the document with [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Alternately, since MongoDB 3.4 you can run an aggregation statement using `$objectToArray` in order to access the keys. But you really only should do this where the collection has millions of documents. The requirements of [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) means the result is in new collection, and not the current one being updated:

```
db.collecion.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "color": {
     "$arrayElemAt": [
       { "$map": {
         "input": { "$objectToArray": "$color" },
         "as": "c",
         "in": "$$c.v"
       }},
       0
     ]
    }
  }},
  { "$out": "newcollection" }
])
```

This works because `$objectToArray` turns your structure like this:

```
"color": { "11": "Gold" }
```

Into this:

```
"color": [{ "k": "11", "v": "Gold" }]
```

So we can then use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator in order to extract the `"color.v"` path value and [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to turn this into a singular value rather than an array.

Generally speaking such conversions would be a lot more complex for aggregation pipeline statements than for what you can achieve simply by manipulating the document structure in code and then writing back to the target collection.

---

Given the existing documents:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59389951fc04695e84e7f4ae"),
        "id" : "1415166669",
        "color" : {
                "14" : "Silver"
        },
        "name" : "Random Name"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59389a75fc04695e84e7f4af"),
        "id" : "1415126969",
        "color" : {
                "11" : "Gold"
        },
        "name" : "Random Name 2"
}
```

Output from both methods is:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59389951fc04695e84e7f4ae"),
        "id" : "1415166669",
        "color" : "Silver",
        "name" : "Random Name"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59389a75fc04695e84e7f4af"),
        "id" : "1415126969",
        "color" : "Gold",
        "name" : "Random Name 2"
}
```

Comment: I am pretty new to mongodb and I do not know much about java script , so I am not able to debug but both of your methods are producing errors. 

I tried to run the javascript function on robomongo shell and it gave the error of unexpected character at line 6( PS:- I updated the wrong bracket problem)

and the aggregate pipeline method is showing an error that addFields is not a correct method

Comment: And that's because I am running mongo 3.2, so I used the update field as below 
db.suggestion_collection.find({}).forEach(function(post){
  db.suggestion_collection.update(
   { _id: post._id },
   { $set:
      {
        color:{ "$arrayElemAt": 
            [ { "$map": 
                { "input": 
                    { "$objectToArray": "$color" }, 
                    "as": "c",
                    "in": "$$c.v" } 
                    }, 0 
                    ] 
} }
}
)


  
});

Comment: But it crashed after just converting a couple of values 
And that too not in the desired format but {color: {"0": "Black"} }

Comment: @AyushAggarwal Sorry for any smally typos and these have been corrected. I have run both of these against the data you supplied in your question and they both work fine. I included the documents used and documents produced in the answer details. As noted in the answer the aggregation statement is only possible in **MongoDB 3.4**. I also noted you "should" be running the JavaScript loop anyway. If you get different results, then **you** are doing something different to the question. This is a response to the "question as asked", and it answers that question completely.

Comment: Yes , I am trying to run this javascript loop as we speak and your responses the question as asked.