# Flattening a nested MongoDB Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is a follow up to

[Flatten a nested object in MongoDB and rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410777/flatten-a-nested-object-in-mongodb-and-rename/44411416?noredirect=1#comment76115198_44411416)

After using the  mentioned answer on that , some of the data types get accepted and they are flattened out while some throw  error

```
  can't convert undefined to object
```

For example:- 
A document on which the data fails:-

```
{
  "id" : "1415304490",
  "color" : {
      "1391" : "Grey"
  },
  "name":"Random Name"
}
```

And the corrosponding function I am using:-

```
db.suggestion.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  var color;
  Object.keys(doc.color).forEach(function(key) {
    color = doc.color[key];
  });

    db.suggestion.update(
       { _id: doc._id },
       { $set: 
           { color: color } 
       }
    );
})
```

It ran on 20,000 prior documents but now failing on this document.

Also If i try to run the same code by running it on a single id , i.e

```
     db.suggest.find({id:"12"})
```

It again works fine as it should be on the same document it was failing earlier.

I also tried to create a work-around as it was running for finding one document each, i.e

```
db.suggestion.find().forEach(function(dest) {
  var id_temp=dest.id;

  db.suggestion.find({id:id_temp}).forEach(function(doc) {
    var color;
    Object.keys(doc.color).forEach(function(key) {
      color = doc.color[key];
    });

    db.suggestion.update(
       { _id: doc._id },
       { $set: 
           { color: color } 
       }
    );
  }) 
})
```

It still fails. I am quite unsure of this weird behaviour of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to make sure the `color` key is actually present. This is why you are getting the error.

```
var ops = [];

db.collection.find({ "color": { "$exists": true } }).forEach(function(doc) {
  var color;
  Object.keys(doc.color).forEach(function(key) {
    color = doc.color[key];
  });
  ops.push(
    { "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": { "$set": { "color": color } }
    }}
  );
  if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
     ops = [];
  }
})

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
   ops = [];
}
```

---

Set up a document:

```
db.collection.insert(
 {
   "id" : "1415304490",
   "color" : {
       "1391" : "Grey"
   },
   "name":"Random Name"
 }
)
```

Run the supplied code on that and get:

```
db.collection.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59430fc4fc23376431161e52"),
        "id" : "1415304490",
        "color" : "Grey",
        "name" : "Random Name"
}
```

Comment: I agree but why should the code fail in the test document i gave above since it does have a color field

Comment: @AyushAggarwal It does not fail. I just copied your document and ran this over it "again". Same result, as it converts it perfectly. My code and not **your** code. The problem as I see it is that you are not simply applying the code you are given. The only reason I would see to not do that is that in fact your documents do not have the structure you say they do. But on the structure presented in the question it works just fine, and of course skips over anything where there is no color key to convert. That's the error in your question, and that is what is addressed.

Comment: I am making edits to your code because while running your script in robomongo , it shows an error in ops=[ ...ops ] as "unknown ." . Hence I have to change it to a workaround and make it update on by one and not in bulk as you are doing . Rest , I think there is a issue in robomongo , I'll run this in shell now. Any other mongodb GUI's that you suggest ?

Comment: @AyushAggarwal Robomongo unforntunately does not support ES6 syntax, so I just made a "very little" alteration to use `.push()` instead of the ES6 way of assigning a immutable array. I generally "recommend" using the plain old [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/), because ( and especially when asking questions here ) everyone has one since it's included in every MongoDB installation. It's also the only place we can "reliably" see how data is actually structured and present, including actual data types. I suggest you get used to that when asking here. Also supports ES6.

Comment: Yeah , after your previous comment I tried using mongo shell and it worked like a charm . Thank you for all your help